# IDE - how to save project and load it? (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I had a class opened in Android Studio, coded it and clicked `CTRL+S`. When I felt safe, for some reasons, I have removed some codes from class and closed IDE (but didnt chosen to save it). After opening the IDE again, it doesnt open the SAVED state of file.... what to do?

Comment: It saved the code you took out without you manually saving it. So it did actually load the "SAVED state"

Comment: Android Studio auto saves everything! `CTRL + S` doesn't do anything in standard settings in `IntelliJ` products. 

If you want to **turn it off**:

Go to `> Settings`

In there search for `auto save` and then go to `System Settings` under `Synchronization`.